# How to create a file using Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to create a .c file from a Makefile. Content of that C file is as follows:

```
char *variable1 = $(VAR1_FROM_MAKEFILE);
char *variable2 = $(VAR2_FROM_MAKEFILE);
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327998/calling-sed-for-a-source-in-makefile-am) on how you can use sed in a makefile.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can use shell redirection to write variables in to source file:

```
VAR1=foobar
all:
    @echo "char *variable1 = \"$(VAR1)\"" > generated.c
```

(the @ sign is here not to have the echo command displayed by make).

---

EDIT: I do not know what's your intent here, but it could be simpler to pass the Makefile variables to the compiler as macro :

```
VAR="toco.conf"
CFLAGS = -DVAR='$(VAR)'
all:
    gcc  $(CFLAGS) prog.c
```

With prog.c being :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    printf("%s\n", VAR);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am currently passing the variable as a marco to the compiler. But this case fails when the value of VAR changes without modifying the Makefile. e.g VAR := $(shell time +%H%M%S)
I want to do this thing is a Makefile for a kernel object. AFAIK There is no "all:" rule in kernel module's Makefile. Otherwise your first solution is great! I know little about Makefiles.

Answer (score 9):

What about the file option of make ?

For Gnu Make:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html

Comment: Doesn't work with make-3.81 at least on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: In fact, requires make 3.82 or later