# ar on MSYS2 shell receives truncated paths when called from Makefile?

Tags: linker, mingw, static-linking, msys, unix-ar

I'm using git-bash.exe from a PortableGit install, with environment variables from a different MinGW. So I have:

```
WORKGROUP+user@AD-X MINGW32 /z/user/Downloads
$ which ar
//WORKGROUP.EX.COM/Users/user/Downloads/mingw-w64/i686-4.9.3-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev1/mingw32/bin/ar

WORKGROUP+user@AD-X MINGW32 /z/user/Downloads
$ gcc --version | head -1
GNU ar (GNU Binutils) 2.25
```

Now there's a library I'm building, and at the end, the link step fails at the call of the `ar` command, which looks something like this:

```
ar -cr "Z:/user/Downloads/MyProjectNameABCDE/someLibraryABC/libs/someLibraryDEFGHI/lib/mingw/libsomeLibraryABCDebug.a" \
Z:/user/Downloads/MyProjectNameABCDE/someLibraryABC/libs/someLibraryDEFGHI/lib/mingw/obj/Debug/libs/someLibraryDEFGHI/test/someObject.o \
[...]
```

... and there's a bunch of objects listed in it - the command line is 10000 characters in length, which is still below `getconf ARG_MAX` of 32000 in MSYS2 shell of PortableGit (`git-bash.exe`). However, the failure I get is `No such file or directory`:

```
\\WORKGROUP.EX.COM\Users\user\Downloads\mingw-w64\i686-4.9.3-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev1\mingw32\bin\ar.exe: Z:/user/Downloads/MyProjectNameABCDE/someLibraryABC/libs/someLibraryDEFGHI/lib/mingw/obj/Debug/libs/some: No such file or directory
```

... and the path given is quite clearly a truncated version of the path where the object files are. What's even stranger, when I copy the full `ar` command line printed by the `make` process, and paste it back in the same terminal, it completes without error?

Would anyone have an idea why this happens, and what could I do to make sure `ar` completes when called from the Makefile?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so first I found in the Makefile where the `ar` command is ran, and I added the `-v` switch to it (so, `-crv`) for verbose.

I could find that most of the command line is read, and objects added, until it comes to about 8192 bytes of the command line, after which it is truncated, and the failure occurs. This is apparently a known issue:

- [How to avoid Max Command line size on Windows](http://gcc-help.gcc.gnu.narkive.com/zqn5ap2b/how-to-avoid-max-command-line-size-on-windows)
- [Solving the 8192 Character Command Line Limit on Windows | MCU on Eclipse](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/03/29/solving-the-8192-character-command-line-limit-on-windows/)

... although, I'm not quite clear on why it should appear in a `make` process which already runs in `git-bash.exe`, that is, a MSYS2 shell ?!

Anyways, the workaround/fix I used is to use the [file option of make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667789/how-to-create-a-file-using-makefile/36646142#36646142), since just doing "@echo $CMD > arscript.sh" from the Makefile will again save only the 8kb truncated command line to file; so instead of the original call:

```
    @$(AR) ${FLAGS_FOR_AR} "$@" $(FILES_FOR_AR)
```

... we save line that to file, and then call `bash` to interpret it as script; that is:

```
    $(file >arscript.sh,@$(AR) ${FLAGS_FOR_AR} "$@" $(FILES_FOR_AR))
    bash -x arscript.sh
```

... and this finally worked for me.